# Resending envelope via Envelopes API errors: "ENVELOPE_NOT_DRAFT"

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the Docusign eSign EnvelopesAPI (PHP) to trigger a resend of an envelope.  This is legacy code that has been running for a number of years, but I'm working on moving it to oAuth.

I find that after updating the API library and changing to oAuth, I'm getting an error when making a call to resent the envelope:

> Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code
> [400] with response Body:
> O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:9:"errorCode";s:18:"ENVELOPE_NOT_DRAFT";s:7:"message";s:113:"The
> requested envelope is not a draft. Not able to update envelope
> properties in an envelope that is not a draft.";}

The envelop is not a draft, but it has never been a draft in the past and we've been able to resend.

Is this a newer requirement that our code was getting around?

The specific call I'm making is:

```
$options = {"advanced_update": NULL, "resend_envelope": true}

$envelopeApi->update($accountId, $envelopeId, $envelope, $options);
```

Answer (score 0):

The body of your request (JSON) should be completely empty

Comment: I tried that and it told me the body is misformatted.  I tried both null and an empty string.  For reference, I'm using API v2.1.

Comment: Can you try to do this from postman? I'm trying to understand if the issue is related to the SDK